# Autoit Script for populating username and password and submit by validating them automatically

Tags: javascript, autoit

I don't have any idea about AutoIT Scripting, I have one AutoIT Script which will run automatically by clicking one button in my tool. With this one webpage will be opened and we need to enter username and password and by submitting it will login to the account. But here I have a task to automate the process of entering the Username and Password and clicking submit button.
I need to read the credentials from the tool and end the process automatically.

I was Successful in reading credentials from tool but I am facing issue in auto submitting the form.

Now when the webpage is opening the username and password are populating automatically, Please help me to click on the submit button automatically by validating the username and Password field in AutoIT Scripting.

Below is the code I have. Please suggest syntax to aut submitting this form by validating username and password fields.

```
    ; ------------------
; Handle login here! ; CHANGE_ME
; ------------------
Local $o_form = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "loginData")

Local $o_user = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "j_username")
;Send("{TAB}")
Local $o_password = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "j_password")
;Send("{TAB}")
Local $o_signin = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "submit")
;Send("{ENTER}")

; Set field values and submit the form
_IEFormElementSetValue ($o_user, $TargetUsername)
_IEFormElementSetValue ($o_password, $TargetPassword)
_IEAction ($o_signin, "Click")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code and just change the values.

```
#include<IE.au3>
$sUsername = "Username"
$sPassword = "Password"
$sUrl = "http://www5.comunio.de/"
$oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 0, 1, 0, 1)
Sleep(2000)
$oHWND = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")
WinSetState($oHWND, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
$oForm = _IEFormGetCollection($oIE, 0)
$oUsername = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, 'ID_LOGON_UserNameText')
$oPassword = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "ID_LOGON_PasswordText")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oUsername, $sUsername)
_IEFormElementSetValue($oPassword, $sPassword)
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually javascript is doing the validation.
In order to trigger it you can use `.focus`, `.click` etc.

You should check if `.click` is already triggering `.focus`.

```
; ------------------
; Handle login here! ; CHANGE_ME
; ------------------
Local $o_form = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "loginData")

Local $o_user = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "j_username")
Local $o_password = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "j_password")
Local $o_signin = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "submit")

; Set field values and submit the form
_IEFormElementSetValue ($o_user, $TargetUsername)
_IEFormElementSetValue ($o_password, $TargetPassword)

$o_user.click
$o_user.focus

$o_password.click
$o_password.focus

$o_signin.focus
$o_signin.click
```